# R: for loop to go over regression models with different weights and save model name

Tags: r, for-loop

Very simple problem but I can't get it or find the solution on line. I want to loop through a regression using different weights and I don't want the output in a list, I want each model as an individual glm object. I am not sure how to loop through the weights through the columns I want.

```
data1 <- mtcars
data1$weight1<- runif(1.5, .9,1.8)
data1$weight_2<- runif(1.5, .9,1.8)
coln<-data1[, c("weight1","weight_2")]

for(i in seq_along(coln)){
  fit[[i]] <- glm(factor(vs) ~ mpg,data=data1,family=quasibinomial,weights = coln[i])
}
```

I think I would need to add `paste0("fit", names(col))` in to get the names right but I'm not sure how to do this. The resulting output I want is simply the following two glm models in the global environment and not in a list.

```
    > fitweight1

Call:  glm(formula = factor(vs) ~ mpg, family = quasibinomial, data = data1, 
    weights = weight1)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          mpg  
      -8.83         0.43  

Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  30 Residual
Null Deviance:      50 
Residual Deviance: 29.1     AIC: NA


> fitweight_2

Call:  glm(formula = factor(vs) ~ mpg, family = quasibinomial, data = data1, 
    weights = weight_2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          mpg  
      -8.83         0.43  

Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  30 Residual
Null Deviance:      54.2 
Residual Deviance: 31.5     AIC: NA
```

Comment: Why do you not want your results in a list? A list is just a collection of individual objects so you can work with them just as if they were not part of a list.

Comment: If you really want the models in individual objects rather than a list, you can iteratively use the `assign()` function to get your models in variables with the name you want.

Comment: To piggyback @divibisan, you never want to flood your global environment with many similar structured objects and `mylist[[1]] == fitweight1`. Yes, right now two does not *flood* the environ but what if you pass hundreds of weights? Plus with a list you can run `lapply`, `Map`, `Filter`, `Reduce` and `do.call` and other bulk operations on each item without needing to find environ names and make separate calls.

Comment: Thanks, I agree about the lists but seeing as it seemed so easy, it was annoying me why I couldn't get it using some `names` approach within the loop as opposed to manually naming them like `mylist[[1]] == fitweight1`. My main issue was getting the weights cycle through the loop which I cant work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
fit <- lapply(coln, function(x) glm(factor(vs) ~ mpg,data=data1,family=quasibinomial,weights = x))
names(fit) <- paste0("fit_", 1:2)             
list2env(fit, globalenv())
print(fit_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider building a list of models with `lapply`, passing in weight column names as argument. And because you are dynamically passing in a string, do not use *data* argument of  `glm` but vectors called with `$` or `[[` qualifiers (recall: dataframe columns are vectors).

Also, consider `replicate` (wrapper to `sapply`) to build your randomized sample of weights if `runif` specifications should remain the same:

```
data1 <- mtcars

# LONG FORM
set.seed(123)
weights <- list(runif(1.5, .9, 1.8), runif(1.5, .9, 1.8))

# SHORT FORM
set.seed(123)
weights <- replicate(n=2, runif(1.5, .9, 1.8), simplify = FALSE)

# ASSIGN NEW COLUMNS
data1[paste0("weight", 1:length(weights))] <- weights     
# RETRIEVE COLUMN NAMES
weight_cols <- names(data1)[grep("weight", names(data1))]

# LIST OF GLM FITTED MODELS
fit_list <- lapply(weight_cols, function(wgt) 
                      glm(factor(data1$vs) ~ data1$mpg,
                          family = quasibinomial, weights = data1[[wgt]])
                  )

# NAME LIST ITEMS
fit_list <- setNames(fit_list, paste0("fit_", weight_cols))
```

**Output**

```
fit_list

$fit_weight1

Call:  glm(formula = factor(data1$vs) ~ data1$mpg, family = quasibinomial, 
    weights = data1[[wgt]])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    data1$mpg  
    -8.8331       0.4304  

Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  30 Residual
Null Deviance:      50.83 
Residual Deviance: 29.59    AIC: NA

$fit_weight2

Call:  glm(formula = factor(data1$vs) ~ data1$mpg, family = quasibinomial, 
    weights = data1[[wgt]])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    data1$mpg  
    -8.8331       0.4304  

Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  30 Residual
Null Deviance:      70.59 
Residual Deviance: 41.1     AIC: NA
```

Comment: Many thanks for a detailed answer, how would you name the list so they correspond to the column names, e.g. `fit_weight1` and `fit_weight_2`?

Comment: Simply name list with `setNames()` using very vector you iterated on, *weightcols*. See edit.

Comment: Thanks for that, `names(fit_list) <- paste0("fit_", weight_cols)` also works, I was just afraid that you have to make sure the order remains the same for these to be correct.

Comment: Correct. `names()` as left-hand operator or `setNames()` as right-hand will work. And order will align since you looped on *weight_cols*.